# Environmental hdri picture not visible

Tags: hdri

[image: hdri not working]

Using an hdri picture as an environmental texture, this is what i get. Only a checkered grey background.
Everything was working fine until this morning. It is the firs time i come across this.

Comment: Transparent film in render properties, maybe.

Comment: I flagged "scene world" in viewport shadin panel